# Rewriting Triple Integral in different order

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How can I rewrite, say:
$$\int^1_0\int^{z^2}_0\int^y_0{f}dxdydz$$
In the orders $dzdxdy$ and $dydzdx$?

Would I have to solve this triple integral all the way or is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: think about the region this represents and represent it using the different variable order; the integrand does not change

Comment: @gt6989b So what does this mean?

Comment: see the hint in the answer

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Your region is defined by the following inequalities, written directly from the integral limits:
$$\begin{split}
&0 \le x \le y \\
&0 \le y \le z^2 \\
&0 \le z \le 1 \\
\end{split}$$
Notice the first integral eliminates $x$ (so only $y,z$ remain) and the second eliminates $y$ (so only $z$ remains) and the last one eliminates $z$

You need to change the inequalities to be in the order defined by desired integration - $dzdxdy$ means you want to eliminate $z$ first by integrating over it, and then $x$ and finally, $y$.

Drawing a picture of the region will help you a lot.

**UPDATE** Let's do one simple example to give you an idea. Suppose I want to integrate $dydxdz$ instead. The last integral is the same, but the first two inequalities will need to be changed.

Assuming $z^2$ is some constant, the first two inequalities describe a triangle in the $x,y$ plane with vertices $(0,0), (0,z^2)$ and $(z^2,z^2)$. Going $x$-first, we bound it $0\le x \le y$ and $0 \le y \le z^2$.

Now we go $y$ first. $y$ changes from the curve $y=x$ to the horizontal line $y=z^2$, so the inequality would be $x \le y \le z^2$ and now $x$ varies from $0$ to $z^2$ to cover the same region. So the ineqialities become
$$
x \le y \le z^2\\
0 \le x \le z^2\\
0 \le z \le 1
$$

Comment: I understood this much already, but how do I change the inequalities?

Comment: @sonia here is an example of a very related problem, just not yours.

Comment: Can you do one of mine and I'll do the second one?

Comment: @sonia why don't you try yours and post the answer here, and i will check it?

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble, can you please do one more example